# Does a file upload with the Parse.com uploader count towards my API request limit?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a 1m row csv which I wish to upload to my Parse.com application using the data uploader.  Will this show as 1m API requests on my request limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to answer my own question, Kevin from Parse.com got back to me in 30 seconds so I can post his response here:

> Yeah, but it's just 1 api request for the whole upload so it's not
>   going to really matter.